# Accessing eloquent list as an array of objects in Laravel 4

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, eloquent, array-filter

I have a Laravel query returning a list. I need to filter this list and pick a random item after filtering.

```
$places = getPlaces();
if ( count($places) > 0) {           
    $places = array_filter($places, "filter"); // 2016/08/25: see http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php

    $randomPlace = $places[rand(0, count($places) - 1)];
}
```

This give an error:

```
array_filter() expects parameter 1 to be array, object give
```

If I cast `$places` to array the error goes but I get nothing:

```
$places = getPlaces();
if ( count($places) > 0) {
    $places = (array)$places;      
    $places = array_filter($places, "filter");

    $randomPlace = $places[rand(0, count($places) - 1)];
}
```

When I check `count($places)` I see there's only one item. The resultset has several.

To get around the filter issue I use Eloquent's `toArray()`:

```
if ( count($places) > 0) {

    $places = $places->toArray();

    $places = array_filter($places, "filter");

    if ( count($places) > 0) {
        $randomPlace = $places[rand(0, count($places) - 1)];
    }

}
```

This works for `filter` but I land into a couple of challenges:

1. I can't access $randomPlace as an object e.g. $randomPlace->name. I have to use array access, $randomPlace['name']. Since there are other methods expecting an object this means having to change/convert all these methods.
2. $places[rand(0, count($places) - 1)] gives an error, e.g.:

   `Undefined offset: 4`

Other than having to change all methods to use `arrays` instead of `objects` (thereby loosing out on functionality), at the moment the only other method off my head is to create a function that iterates over $places and and puts the objects into an array.

Is there a better way of handling this?

Thanks.

Comment: You can either use the collection method `$places->filter('filter')` or try getting the values only, using `array_values($places)`. My guess is that `array_filter` preserves the keys and removed the item where key=4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're working with a collection and are tripping up when converting it to an array in which you can use `array_filter` on. Instead, use the built-in collection methods for filtering and retrieving a random element:

```
$randomItem = $places->filter('filter')->random();
```

In the example above, the argument to the `filter()` method is the name of your filter function. I'd recommend calling it something other than `filter` to increase readability. :)

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly. It was also great learning about collections in PHP. One thing I noticed, though, the collections' `filter` does not take a `string` as a parameter but a `closure`.